# How to Reverse owl carousel slider slide from right to left

Tags: jquery, slider, owl-carousel

I want to reverse slider for Arabic language so slider behavior reverse.

> Prevoius [1] [2] [3] [4] [5] [6] [7] [8] [9] [10] Next

Assume that here 1 to 10 is block that content some heading and description.

so here i want reverse of these sequence 1th is at position of 10th and 10th is at 1th position so what should i do?

Finally i want

> Next [10] [9] [8] [7] [6] [5] [4] [3] [2] [1] Prevoius

Comment: you can float it to right for each one

Comment: Here in slider at a time display only 4 block so it cant posible..

Comment: if answer not work please provide your html code

Comment: it is not work in v1.3.2 this is available in 2.0.0

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Here's the specification to scroll from right to left:

https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/demos/rtl.html

As you can see it's simply using the owl variable **rtl** giving it a true value like so:

`$('.your-carousel').owlCarousel({
rtl:true
});`

Comment: Is there any option to move slides continues instead of reverse back.?

Comment: @MuddasirAbbas did you ever find out how to do that? Continuing in same direction...

Answer (score 0):

You can use Jump method, jump to last slide like this (i jump to slide 5)

```js
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    var owl = $("#owl-demo");
    owl.owlCarousel({
        //owl options
    });


   var owls = $(".owl-carousel").data('owlCarousel'); 
   owls.goTo(5);

    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The fastest way is putting this in siperbox.css

```
#swipebox-container{
direction: ltr;
}
```

Thanks